# Android google play app

Tags: android

I submitted my app on google play yesterday..my app has some downloads today on the google play developer site.  My question is why do I need to include the name of my app in quotes to have the google play search find it?  There are no quotes in the name of my app when I created it.

Comment: The Google Play search is a keyword based search, by including your app name in quotes you are saying that everything within the quotes is one keyword

Comment: So if I search My game it won't find anything but it will find it if I do "My game". How do I fix that? Ppl prob don't see it if they have to use quotes

Comment: Don't worry.  You have to be in the store for a while to get name recognition or create something that goes viral.  Sorry don't mean to break your bubble but you always get a couple downloads I think they are automated playstore search engines.

Comment: you need to make a one word title for your app.  My app is bestrides you can probably find it in the playstore.  This is do it yourself free add.  Post to your facebook, google+.  Make a qr code print it out and plaster it around where people may use your app or where people use their phones.